# Why does my HTML string resource only work with &lt;

Tags: android, html, string, kotlin

I'm trying to apply formatting to a String literal using fromHtml()

My string (foo) is something like: `aaa<br/><b>bbb</b><br/><br/><b>ccc</b>`

However, when calling `tv.text = Html.fromHtml(context.getString(R.string.foo), FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)` the text loses the tags.

I found out reading the [String Resources documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource) that if you use both styling and formatting (passing arguments to String literal), you must write your HTML like this `&lt;b> &lt;b/>`, this does work for me but I'm not taking any args in that string so I'm wondering why it's behaving like this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that the [<br>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-br-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.